# Complicated key sequences

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime 3 doesn't catch complicated key sequences. 
i.e. it interprets "ctrl+tab+s" and "ctrl+s" both as "ctrl+s".
There are no any restrictions in ST documentation for binding such sequences. Is it feature or bug ST3? Is it possible to bind to command these sequences?

OS - Ubuntu 16.04
ST - 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not specifically documented anywhere, but my guess would be that since <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> are both "regular" keys, as soon as one of them is pressed a keyboard event is fired that represents that key, which would stop you from being able to bind multiple distinct keys together in one simultaneous binding.

As such, a complicated key binding that includes multiple keys in addition to modifier keys is likely not possible. However, Sublime supports chorded key bindings that allow you to specify that multiple key presses have to appear in sequence, so you could use something like that for this.

An example of that is the default key binding for toggling the side bar:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+b"], 
    "command": "toggle_side_bar" 
},
```

Here you need to press <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> to toggle the state. Generally you would invoke a key binding like this by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> throughout and just tapping <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> in sequence.